# How to choose a default option in daterangepicker for first loading in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I'm a new user for bootstrap.

I used a daterangepicker as picture:

[image]

But I need to really choose a default option when page loading, e.g "Last 7 Days".

I really need set default and active all function binded to this option, like I click on it.

Please help me.

Thanks,
Jame

Comment: Is this really bootrap? It looks like moment.js.

Comment: If it's moment function, it sets selected the first one from the list, just move up the one you want to be selected.

Comment: Could you show me how to move up?

Comment: Please provide your code to have a better picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My function is below.

```
cb(moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month'));

jQuery('#yourdivID').daterangepicker({
    "showWeekNumbers": true,
    "dateLimit": {
        "days": 365 //181=days in 6 months, 365=days in a year
    },
    "ranges": {
        //'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        //'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        //'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
}, cb);
```

Note: you will need moment.js if you go by this as is.

If you use it like below, you will have 7 days gap.

```
cb(moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment());
```